# Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module

Tags: reactjs, npm-install, sharp

I already do what the error said. I removed the sharp then `npm install --ignore-scripts=false --verbose` but it still doesn't work.

I also tried the:

```
rimraf node_modules 
rimraf yarn.lock 
yarn
```

What might the problem here?

npm: 6.13.4

node: v10.18.0

python: 3.7.0

sharp: ^0.26.2

windows 10 pro 64-bit

```
!  Error: 
Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module      

\\?\C:\Users\ph2200009\Desktop\TM\cplus_incident_mgnt\functions\node_modules\sharp\build\Release\sharp.node is not a valid Win32 application.
\\?\C:\Users\ph2200009\Desktop\TM\cplus_incident_mgnt\functions\node_modules\sharp\build\Release\sharp.node     

- Remove the "node_modules/sharp" directory then run    
  "npm install --ignore-scripts=false --verbose" and look for errors

at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ph2200009\Desktop\TM\cplus_incident_mgnt\functions\node_modules\sharp\lib\constructor.js:34:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)  
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ph2200009\Desktop\TM\cplus_incident_mgnt\functions\node_modules\sharp\lib\index.js:3:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)  
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ph2200009\Desktop\TM\cplus_incident_mgnt\functions\helpers\image.js:1:15)   
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
!  We were unable to load your functions code. (see above)
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have an **Apple M1 chip**, try the following:

```bash
brew install vips

npm rebuild --verbose sharp
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this rebuild command to fix it:

```
npm rebuild --verbose sharp
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! finally a solution that works

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `node_modules` folder by typing `rm -rf node_modules` in terminal and then type `npm i` and after that try to install `sharp` again by `npm i sharp`

Comment: I already did that.
`rimraf node_modules`
`rimraf yarn.lock`
`yarn`

Still doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

For my Apple M1 Chip this is the only thing that worked:

```
npm rebuild --arch=arm64 --platform=linux sharp
```

Answer (score 0):

just want to document what code solved this for myself. it was

```
yarn add sharp
```